# How to submit multiple PHP forms while each form has its own submit button?

Tags: php

I've generated some forms using a php loop like this:

```
 <?php
    while ($rowTechmen = $techmenQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
       <form method="post">
         <input type="text" name="textbox1"/>
         <button type="submit" name="submit1">Submit</button>
       </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

And now I have some similar forms with each form having its own submit button. I don't want to submit them all with one single button. How can I grab `$_POST` values and update my database with new values from each form?

Comment: You can have one big form with multiple submit buttons

Comment: Do you want to submit them all OR only that form whose button has been clicked ?

Comment: This is not "one" big form! Each loop generates a single standalone form, as you can see.

Comment: @Rohit.007 Only the form being clicked.

Comment: then your code should work. What problem are you facing?

Comment: Make one form that contains all fields from all your seperate forms?

Comment: If you keep having multiple forms you will then submit them one by one. So make it a unique form if you need to submit all the data.

Comment: The problem is that all forms have similar button/input names and when I click one button, it generates errors @Rohit.007

Comment: I need multiple forms as every form should have a "delete" buttons as well. @kerbholz

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Yes the forms should have unique input/button names, but how? @AymDev

Comment: Then I think you'd need Javascript to collect all data from all your forms and submit that data.

Comment: @RezaKazemifar By adding a suffix to the names, like an id, or something unique. But we have no idea what is the data, your forms are empty.

Comment: @AymDev Can't I use foreach loop or put [] in front of input/button names?

Comment: There is one best solution , you have to generate unique ids for textbox and the submit button for different dynamic forms. I'm not getting what is the use of the loop actually , anyway pass some unique values in ids of the textboxes and submit buttons and you will get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate your forms, use a variable to increment:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($rowTechmen = $techmenQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="textbox"/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit_<?php echo $i ?>">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php
    $i += 1;
}
?>
```

Then if you need to identify which form was submitted, you can do:

```
// When a form is submitted
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {

    // Get the submit number
    $submit_name = preg_grep("/submit_/", array_keys($_POST));
    $submit_id = ($parts = explode('_', $submit_name[1]))[1];

    // Display the data for testing
    var_dump($submit_id);
    echo $_POST['textbox'];
}
```

Of course you can replace `$i` with an *ID* from your database. Documentation of the used functions:

- [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)
- [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm. Thank you very much. While I had to change offsets to [0], they are perfect.

Comment: Glad it worked. It might be better as I don't know `preg_grep()` much. Accept the answer if it solved your issue ;)

Comment: @AymDev Similar to my suggestion and you have voted down my solution that's really great. I appreciate the efforts.

Comment: @Rohit.007 I just removed the downvote as you edited your answer but you did not provide a solution about how to identify the form (which could be important as your names where just `rand()` for both `<input>` and `<button>` without prefix to identify them)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    for ($i = 0; $i< 10 ;$i++) {
    ?>
       <form method="post" name="form">
         <input type="text" name="textbox"/>
         <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
         <button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete">Delete</button>
       </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: How would you catch that ?

Comment: How can I get post values then?

Comment: @Rohit.007 I'll remove the downvote if you provide the answer to my previous comment.

Comment: I understood, without `key` name you can't get the variable value but still you can post the `random` key in hidden variable. anyways updated the code which is having 10 form and different naming for each button doesn't required.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wide question. So There are many ways in which this can be achieved. So I think it’s better to teach the flow instead of throwing a code snippets.

Basically it’s all about getting values through js using dom and sending it all to backend through ajax, etc. if you use some js libraries like vue, angular it would be easier as it uses other http libraries and  bindings.

If you are using basic js and ajax. Here is how it goes

1 - prevent default of the forms submit

2 - when the user clicks the all in one submit(button) using js get all the values of the forms elements

3 - after getting the values by using ajax post it to the url

Comment: Thank you @aimme. I tried to be most specific when asking the question. While your answer is so wider and more general than my question. :-)